# [libpng]could not link symlink include/libpng16/png.h

Tags: libpng

When I install imageMagick,it told me must link `libpng` before install imageMagick.

Then I link the `libpng`,it occur this issue

> > brew link libpng
> >     Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.17...
> >     Error: Could not symlink include/libpng16/png.h
> >     Target /usr/local/include/libpng16/png.h
> >     already exists. You may want to remove it:
> >       rm '/usr/local/include/libpng16/png.h'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:

```
brew link --overwrite libpng
```

To list all files that would be deleted:

```
brew link --overwrite --dry-run libpng
```

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Answer (score 0):

solved it.

sudo chmod -R 777  /usr/local/include/libpng16

brew link --overwrite libpng

brew install imagemagick